# limit how many dynamic form fields are shown and validate as image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following jquery enabled javascript:

```
<form>
    <input type="file">
</form>

jQuery(function($) {

  $('form').delegate('input[type=file]', 'change', function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.append('<input type="file">');
  });

});
```

it will dynamically add a file upload field as the user add files they want to upload. how can I limit it to images only, and stop adding new fields after they've added 5 images?

I'm trying to switch from having numerous field, which I validated as images like so:

```
var valid_extensions = /(.gif|.jpg|.jpeg|.png)$/i;
function CheckExtension(fld){
  if (valid_extensions.test(fld.value)) return true;
  alert('only gif, png or jpg formats are allowed!');
  fld.select();
  fld.value="";
  fld.focus();
  return false;
}

<input type="file" onChange="return CheckExtension(this);">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing your goal, you should rewrite your function:

```
var checkExtension;
var valid_extensions = /(.gif|.jpg|.jpeg|.png)$/i;
var limit = 5; // define the limit of rows here
var i = 0;
$('form').delegate("input[type=file]", "change", function () {
    if (i < limit && checkExtension(this)) {
        $('form').append( $("<input>").attr({type: "file"}) );
    }
    i++;
});
checkExtension = function (fld) {
    if (valid_extensions.test(fld.value)) return true;
    alert('only gif, png or jpg formats are allowed!');
    fld.select();
    fld.value="";
    fld.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: do I just wrap that with `script` tags or do is wrap it with the full `<script>jQuery(function($) { ..your code.. });</script>` ? I tried both, and it's validating an image only but now its not loading the next file field

Comment: I had to change `$('form').append( $("<input>").attr({type: file}) );` to `$('form').append( $('<input type="file">') );`

Comment: Ah... I was missing the quotes around `type: "file"` Either methods should work now, and no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5's [`accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input) attribute to specify which mimetypes you will accept.

For your limit, a simple incrementing integer and a ternary should handle it, like so:

```
var i = 0;
$('form').delegate('input[type=file]', 'change', function() {
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  i < 5 ? form.append('<input type="file">') : "";
  i++;
});
```

If you want to use javascript, a google search returned this Stack Overflow answer:
[Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: thanks, the limit part works great, but `accept` is not fully cross-browser compatible which is why I didn't go with my prior method.

Comment: Right, then the answer I posted should be of best use to you.

Comment: my `CheckExtension` function above works great in all browsers (that I've tested so far), how can I combine that with the new javascript code?

Comment: when I tried `i < 5 ? form.append('<input type="file" onChange="return CheckExtension(this);">') : "";` it worked, but it still makes an addition upload field when the file is not an image. if the file is not an image can't I stop it from creating the next upload field?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Austin, here is the final code that works for me. it will dynamically create a file input field and accept images only. I'm still testing, but this **should** work in all browsers that support js.

```
<form>
<input type="file">

<script>
jQuery(function($) {

    var checkExtension;
    var valid_extensions = /(.gif|.jpg|.jpeg|.png)$/i;
    var limit = 5; // define the limit of rows here
    var i = 1;
    $('form').delegate("input[type=file]", "change", function () {
        if (i < limit && checkExtension(this)) {
            $('form').append( $('<input type="file">') );
        }
        i++;
    });
    checkExtension = function (fld) {
        if (valid_extensions.test(fld.value)) return true;
        alert('only gif, png or jpg formats are allowed!');
        fld.select();
        fld.value="";
        fld.focus();
        return false;
    }

});
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: if anyone see any possible problems with this, please let me know as I am always open to suggestions and improvement